# Algorithm to reduce text based on word frequency

Tags: php, regex, string, text, logic

How to reduce a text based on word frequency in PHP?

For example, if I have this text:

`house house house house book book book`

it should be reduced to something like this (or any similar form):

`house house book`

so this way the most used word is still house by 2 and book by 1.

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: @Andreas okay, How do I reduce a text based on the example above? So far, I simply have an extremely long string where some words are repeated over 1k times. How do I fix this?

Comment: Read up on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78 there is also a few videos about the topic on youtube https://www.google.se/search?biw=1239&bih=680&tbm=vid&ei=xujvWqmqLcG9sQHXmYUg&q=lz77+algorithm&oq=LZ+77+&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i19k1l10.55866.57062.0.58875.6.6.0.0.0.0.153.733.1j5.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.6.730...0j0i131k1j0i10k1j0i13k1j0i13i30k1.0.Zv6a7YdPB54

Comment: and what's the output of this string `house book house abcd book house book`??

Comment: @YashParekh depends on how many times house and book are repeated. Honestly, in my situation, the words that are used the least, should disappear. So, for a text with let's say 200k words, I should get the most used 200 words, but each word should be repeated x times such that we still get a string which correlates with the original string.

Comment: So, you are actually after the word frequency? Maybe you should explain what's your overall goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is actually interesting. As I understand it, it is not about compression but word frequency - and this my friend, is the field of natural language processing.

My first thought was: Recommend using [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/) (and learning Python if required) since there is no real PHP equivalent to it (the closest library is probably [NlpTools](http://php-nlp-tools.com/)). However, it turned out Dan Cardin, an early NlpTools contributor, created a separate library that deals with your very problem: [yooper/php-text-analysis](https://github.com/yooper/php-text-analysis)

> PHP Text Analysis is a library for performing Information Retrieval
>   (IR) and Natural Language Processing (NLP) tasks using the PHP
>   language

Add PHP Text Analysis to your project

```
composer require yooper/php-text-analysis
```

Here is an example how to use it:

```
<?php

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$book = file_get_contents('pg74.txt'); // tom sawyer from the gutenberg project http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/74/pg74.txt

// Create a tokenizer object to parse the book into a set of tokens
$tokenizer = new \TextAnalysis\Tokenizers\GeneralTokenizer();
$tokens = $tokenizer->tokenize($book);

$freqDist = new \TextAnalysis\Analysis\FreqDist($tokens);

//Get the top 10 most used words in Tom Sawyer 
$top10 = array_splice($freqDist->getKeyValuesByFrequency(), 0, 10);
```

The call to `freq_dist` returns a [FreqDist](https://github.com/yooper/php-text-analysis) instance.

Then, you can then calculate the weights of words yourself (freq/numberOfAllTokens) or use the `getKeyValuesByWeight()` method.

```
$top10[0]/$freqDist->getTotalTokens();
$weights = $freqDist->getKeyValuesByWeight();
```

... or normalize the frequency of your selected words by the occurrence of your least frequent top word, e.g.

```
foreach ($top10 as $word => $freq) {
    $relWeight[$word] = $freq/end($top10);
}
```

Depending on your input, you will find that your most frequent words are `a`, `the`, `that`, etc. This is why you want to remove [stopwords](https://github.com/yooper/php-text-analysis/blob/af647a6b6eb29ebb8f5a8bd68634f2c39be5b7ac/tests/TextAnalysis/Filters/StopWordsFilterTest.php). And we have only started..

[Here](https://github.com/yooper/php-text-analysis/blob/af647a6b6eb29ebb8f5a8bd68634f2c39be5b7ac/tests/TextAnalysis/Filters/StopWordsFilterTest.php) are some more samples.

Answer (score 1):

Compress & Uncompress a string in PHP: gzcompress,gzuncompress

**Example:**

```
$text = "house house house house book book book";
echo "Orignal text lenght : ". strlen($text)."<br>";
$compressed = gzcompress($text, 9);
echo "Compressed text: ".$compressed."<br>";
echo "Compress text length :". strlen($compressed);
echo "<br>";
echo "Uncompressed text :".$uncompressed = gzuncompress($compressed);
```

**Output:**

Orignal text length: 38

Compressed text: x���/-NU�� ����R

Compress text length: 22

Uncompressed text : house house house house book book book